# UserDataSource doesnt have data property in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to add multiselect to an Angular Material table following [this guide](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#selection). It makes reference to `data` in masterToggle, but I don't have that property in my UserDataSource. What is the correct way to fix this?

My Component

```
dataSource: UserDataSource;

ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new UserDataSource(this.svc);
    this.dataSource.loadCompanies(this.lgid);
}
masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected() ?
        this.selection.clear() :
        this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
}
```

User Data Source:

```
export class UserDataSource implements DataSource<Company> {

private CompanyModelsSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Company[]>([]);
private loadingSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
public loading$ = this.loadingSubject.asObservable();

constructor(private svc: GreencardService) { }

connect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): Observable<Company[]> {
    return this.CompanyModelsSubject.asObservable();
}

disconnect(collectionViewer: CollectionViewer): void {
    this.CompanyModelsSubject.complete();
    this.loadingSubject.complete();
}

loadCompanies(lgid)
{
    this.loadingSubject.next(true);
    this.svc.getCompanies(lgid).pipe(
        catchError(() => of([])),
        finalize(() => this.loadingSubject.next(false))
    ).subscribe(x => { this.CompanyModelsSubject.next(x);});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you are following I believe is using the `MatTableDataSource` class, which has a public getter `data`...

```
get data() { return this._data.value; }
```

And the private variable `_data` is the `BehaviorSubject` with the initialized data.

```
 constructor(initialData: T[] = []) {
    super();
    this._data = new BehaviorSubject<T[]>(initialData);
    this._updateChangeSubscription();
  }
```

---

Because you created your own class, you will need to implement a similar public getter... possibly like below.

```
get data() {return this.CompanyModelsSubject.value; }
```

---

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/bc8fc75bf8af82378077d7c2277e31a1dcd6aac9/src/lib/table/table-data-source.ts#L62